# Find cell that has string listed in array then use other array to replace it

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to replace strings, listed in my array, within the cell with strings in another array, that abbreviate the name.

Example:

| My Stuff |
| --- |
| **Nike** Shoes |
| **Adidas** Pants |
| **Puma** Shoes |
| **The North Face** Jacket |
| **S & S Activewear** Shirt |
| **CORE 365** Shirt |

**INTO**

| My Stuff |
| --- |
| **NK** Shoes |
| **AD** Pants |
| **PM** Shoes |
| **NF** Jacket |
| **SA** Shirt |
| **C3** Shirt |

Here is what I have so far:

```vb
Function AbrivBrand(strInput As String) As String

Dim brandArray() As String, strColor As String, e As Long

    'items are sorted by length...
    brandArray = Split("Adidas,Nike,Puma,The North Face,S & S Activewear,CORE 365", ",")
    
    abrivArray = Split("AD,NK,PM,NF,SA,C3", ",")
    
    strBrand = strInput
    
    For Each e In brandArray
    
        If InStr(LCase(strBrand), LCase(e)) > 0 Then
        'not sure what I can do so it replaces Adidas with AD
            AbrivBrand = Replace(strBrand, e, abrivArray)
            Exit Function
        End If
        
    Next e
    
    AbrivBrand = strBrand
End Function
```

I put the LCase() is so that it is not case sensitive.

If possible, I would like to add more arrays to abbreviate more things like Shirt, Pants, Jacket into SH, PNT, JCKT etc.

Comment: You will want to change to a standard for loop. `For i = Lbound(brandArray,1) to Ubound(brandArray,1)`  Then you would use `LCase(brandArray(i))` instead of `LCase(e)` and then it is `AbrivBrand = Replace(strBrand, brandArray(i), abrivArray(i))`

Comment: If you have a lot of values to check then a table on a worksheet would be an easier place to edit/maintain them than hard-coded in your VBA.  And `Instr()` has a flag for case-sensitivity: Eg: `Instr(1, "BAAB", "aA", vbTextCompare)` gives `2`